# Xamarin/ C# Tabbed page Zxing Scanner Issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have tab page and it have 3 pages inside. In first and second page i need to use ZXingScannerView. But when i put scannerview to both pages its giving me error while deploying project. Error is :
`Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'getParameters failed (empty parameters)'` 
How can i fix that ? I tried use ScannerPages with buttons instead of scannerview but I must use scannerview to both pages. How can i fix it ? Thanks for replies!

That camera should stay open always in half of my form thats why i must use scannerview.

My TabChange event code :

```
 private void TabPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ZXingScannerView Zxingview = new ZXingScannerView();

            MessagingCenter.Send<ZXingScannerView>(Zxingview, "ZXingView");
        }
```

My Subscribe in another page :

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ZXingScannerView>(this, "ZXingView", (value) =>
        {
            grd.Children.Add(value); //grd is grid

        });
```

Comment: pages in a TabbedPage are all active at the same time, so you probably have two different views competing for control of the camera

Comment: @Jason Yes maybe thats why. So when i change page how can i close first one then open 2nd for not control them in same time ?

Comment: you would need to hook into the tab change event

Comment: @Jason I'm trying with messaging center in to tab change event now but still not working. I sending like this : ( I Edit my Question you can see code in there )
But When i open 2 page its giving same error again. I think i must close first view first then open 2nd one but i dont know how can i close first one. Can you help me about it too ? I'm sorry for bother you.

Comment: please do not post code in comments, it is impossible to read

Comment: @Jason Sorry i edit my question i added my code to there